# Google Apps Script: Find the location of every item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, indexof

I would like to run through every item in a 1D array and perform an indexOf on another 1D array to determine where it matches.

If I have:

```
Array 1 = ["a","d","e"]
Array 2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

I would like to transform Array 1 from values into match locations where it would become: `[0,3,4]`.

I tried the equation below, but it didn't work. I thought using **forEach()** I could go through every item in Array 1. Then I could run a function to perform an **indexOf()** on Array 2 for each item. What am I doing wrong??

```
var array1 = ["a","d","e"];
var array2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var array1count = array1.forEach( function (e) { array2.indexOf( e )});

Logger.log(array1count)
```

Comment: is `array1` sorted like `array2`?

Comment: no the order of each array is random. In the example I gave they are sorted alphabetically by coincidence but the use case version is not.

Answer (score 4):

If `array1` has the same order as `array2`, you could take a closure over the index and use a while loop inside of the callback for mapping found indices.

```js
var array1 = ["a", "d", "e"],
    array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    indices = array1.map((i => v => {
        while (array2[++i] !== v) ;
        return i;
    })(-1));

console.log(indices); // [0, 3, 4]
```

For not defined order, you neeeither a single loop for gathering the indices and another to map the collected indices.

```js
var array1 = ["a", "d", "e"],
    array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    indices = array1.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        array2.reduce((m, v, i) => m.set(v, i), new Map)
    );

console.log(indices); // [0, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach()` returns `undefined`, you can try using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

```js
var array1 = ["a","d","e"];
var array2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var array1count = array2.reduce(function(acc, curr, i) { 
  if(array1.includes(curr)) //check if the current item is present in array1 
    acc.push(i);
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(array1count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this equation and it worked. Seems to be pretty simple and straightforward. Hopefully I'm not missing something here that the other answers are resolving.

```
var array1 = ["a","d","e"];
var array2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var array1count = array1.map( function (item) { return array2.indexOf(item) });

Logger.log(array1count)
```

Comment: Oh...if only you could understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61288898/)! In programming, We mainly deal with time and space complexity- In layman terms, how fast and sleek the code can run. Your code: `indexOf` loops through array2 to find `item`. It does this for every `item` in `array1`. So, if there are `n` items in both arrays, no.of items to load = nxn = n^2(exponential). Not only does that answer deal with it with in n+n=`2n`(linear), it does it so elegantly. [Ref](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

Comment: Yes I am too inexperienced right now and was unable to appreciate this answer but I appreciate you directing me to the time and space concept and for showing me how it applies here!!