# Getting each cell value from a range of cells in google app script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script which pulls data from the products sheet from either r[3] if the currency is "EURO" in column O of the JOB sheet, or r[2] if the currency is "STERLING" in column O of the job sheet. The problem is that when the script runs it is not differentiating between the currencies according to each row in the job sheet. The script is reading the currency value in the last row and using that value to input the value from either r[2] or r[3] of the products sheet instead of reading the currency value from each of the rows. Thank you for any help resolving this issue
The job sheet can be viewed at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1up7cUvQqL-LcA7EeuM65B0zjcRT46LGwN2x3C_4j0bY/edit?usp=sharing
The products sheet can be viewed at
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pt7YnN9fmoD4PE0o9oVPezK8Qz6ZmabyJbWXfdzFeMU/edit?usp=sharing

```
function updatePrice() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var jobSheet = ss.getSheetByName('JOBS');
  var productSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pt7YnN9fmoD4PE0o9oVPezK8Qz6ZmabyJbWXfdzFeMU").getSheetByName('PRODUCTS');
  
  var objEuro = productSheet.getRange("A2:D" + productSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) =>  (o[r[0]] = r[3], o), {});
  var objSterling = productSheet.getRange("A2:D" + productSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) =>  (o[r[0]] = r[2], o), {});
  var range = jobSheet.getRange("P2:AK" + jobSheet.getLastRow());
  var euroValues = range.getValues().map(r => [objEuro[r[0]] || null]);
  var sterlingValues = range.getValues().map(r => [objSterling[r[0]] || null]);
  var vs = jobSheet.getRange("O2:P"+ jobSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r) => {  
    
    if(r[0] == "EURO" && r[1].match(/^A/i)  ){
  range.offset(0, 10, euroValues.length, 1).setValues(euroValues)};
  
  if(r[0] == "STERLING" && r[1].match(/^A/i)  ){
  range.offset(0, 10, sterlingValues.length, 1).setValues(sterlingValues)}});

}
```

Comment: I would prefer seeing an image of your sheet to visualize you issue.

Comment: Please share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet with desired output. Remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the links to the JOBS spreadsheet and the PRODUCTS spreadsheet. In column Z it lists the values which the script is pulling from the PRODUCTS sheet. Column AB lists the correct values I require the script to bring across. I hope this is clearer to follow. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Les by what do you mean by r[3] r[2]?

Comment: @Logan It's a reference to a zero-based column Index. He's mapping data using an array  `r`. For Products, the Euro value is in Column D (index=4, zero-based = 3) , hence r[3]; the Sterling value is in Column C (index=3, zero-based=2), hence r[2]. (I'm not saying that the code is correct, just trying interpret the intent).

Comment: I'm referring getting the currency value from either column C orcolumn D in the PRODUCTS sheet

Comment: @Cooper I have edited the post to include the links to the JOBS spreadsheet and the PRODUCTS spreadsheet. In column Z it lists the values which the script is pulling from the PRODUCTS sheet. Column AB lists the correct values I require the script to bring across. I hope this is clearer to follow. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you will consider this as an answer to your question.

I was unable to follow the map command for the objects (`var euroValues = range.getValues().map(r => [objEuro[r[0]] || null])` and `var sterlingValues = range.getValues().map(r => [objSterling[r[0]] || null]);`), so I just wrote it old-school:

- finding the indices of each Job Product in the Product Sheet (h/t [Google Apps Script: Find the location of every item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61288898/1330560)),
- assigning the price to a temporary array,
- updating the price range in a single `setValues` at the end of the script.

---

```
function updatePrice() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var jobSheet = ss.getSheetByName('JOBS');
  var productSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pt7YnN9fmoD4PE0o9oVPezK8Qz6ZmabyJbWXfdzFeMU").getSheetByName('PRODUCTS');
  
  // get products and jobs
  var products = productSheet.getRange("A2:D" + productSheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
  var jobsRange = jobSheet.getRange("O2:AK" + jobSheet.getLastRow())
  var jobs = jobsRange.getValues()

  // get the list of products on the Jobs sheet and Product Codes on the products sheet
  var jobProducts = jobs.map(function(e){return e[1]})
  var prodCodes = products.map(function(e){return e[0]})  
  // find the indices of every Job in the Product array
  var indices = jobProducts.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        prodCodes.reduce((m, v, i) => m.set(v, i), new Map)
    );

  var priceArray = []

  // for each job get the Products index and the Price and push the price onto an array
  for (var i=0;i<jobProducts.length;i++){

    // assign value depending whether currency = Sterling or Euro
    if (jobs[i][0] === "STERLING"){
      var productValue = products[indices[i]][2]
    }
    else if (jobs[i][0] === "EURO"){
      var productValue = products[indices[i]][3]
   }
    priceArray.push([productValue])
  }
  jobsRange.offset(0, 12,jobs.length,1).setValues(priceArray)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tedinoz, it's working perfect, exactly what's needed.